# How to store the parsed data in the array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, struct

I have a database on Firebase. I parse some data that I want to store in the array of structures:
*postData.swift*

```
struct postData {
  let Title: String
  let Subtitle: String
  let imgURL: String
  let Date: String

  init(Title: String, Subtitle: String, imgURL: String, Date: String) {
    self.Title = Title
    self.Subtitle = Subtitle
    self.imgURL = imgURL
    self.Date = Date
  }
}
```

This array will be used for creating a *collectionViewCells* inside a **tableViewCells**. Inside my ViewController I created a global array  `var dataPosts:[postData] = []` where I will store parsed data.
Here is a function I made:

```
var dataPosts:[postData] = []
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .grouped)
       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self
       ...
       tableView.register(PostCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: PostTableID)
       parsePosts()
       print(dataPosts.count) // prints 0
   }
   
   func parsePosts() {
       let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Посты")
       var data:[postData]
       databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
           for child in snapshot.children {
               let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
               let res = snap.value as! [String: Any]
               
               let title = res["Заголовок"] as! String
               let subtitle = res["Подзаголовок"] as! String
               let img = res["URL"] as! String
               let date = res["Дата"] as! String
               
               self.dataPosts.append(postData(Title: title, Subtitle: subtitle, imgURL: img, Date: date))
               print(self.dataPosts.count, " - inside cycle") // prints 1
           }
       }
       data = dataPosts
       print(data.count, " - inside function") // prints 0
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataPosts.count
   }
```

Is there any way to store it in the array? Or I should use something from OOP (I'm a beginner)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a suggestion, instead of creating a `struct` create a `NSObject` class instead:

```
import UIKit

class PostData: NSObject {
    
    @objc var title: String?
    @objc var subtitle: String?
    @objc var imgUrl: String?
    @objc var date: String?
    
    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        
        self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String
        self.subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String
        self.imgUrl = dictionary["imgUrl"] as? String
        self.date = dictionary["date"] as? String
        
    }
}
```

Make sure that the dictionary values such as the title, subtitle, etc. match with your firebase database values names. I think that yours may be:

```
init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.title = dictionary["Заголовок"] as? String
    self.subtitle = dictionary["Подзаголовок"] as? String
    self.imgUrl = dictionary["URL"] as? String
    self.date = dictionary["Дата"] as? String
}
```

This way now when reading data you can initialize a PostData object with the dictionary from snapshot and append it to your array (If using it).

EXAMPLE:

```
// Here you had already observed a single event

if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let postData = PostData(dictionary: postDict)

    // append to array if needed
    self.postsData.append(newElement: postData)

}
```

REMEMBER that with your object we are working with optionals values, that means that you may need to use `guard let` or `if let` statements to make sure this properties are not nil (this may not be the case if this are correctly parsed with your firebase database).

EXAMPLE:

```
// Let's suppose that you need to access to the "title" property

// This dictionary is a hardcoded dictionary, yours may be downloaded from your database
let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "title": "a title" as AnyObject,
    "subtitle": "a subtitle" as AnyObject,
    "imgUrl": "an imgUrl" as AnyObject,
    "date": "a date" as AnyObject
]

let postData = PostData(dictionary: dictionary)

// THIS IS THE INCORRECT WAY
let postTitle = postData.title
print(postTitle!) /* The print statement does not require a non-optional value, but may print something like: Optional("a title"), in your case you may want a non-optional value */

// THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY
if let postTitle = postData.title {
    print(postTitle) // Prints: "a title"
}

// ALTERNATIVE TO CORRECT WAY
guard let postTitle = postData.title else { return }
print(postTitle) // Prints: "a title"
```

This may helps you to write less lines of code and make it simple to understand.

COMPLETE EXAMPLE:

```
var postsDataArray = [PostData]()

func parsePosts() {
   let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Посты")
   
   databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
       
       if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

           let postData = PostData(dictionary: postDict)

           self.postsDataArray.append(newElement: postData)

       }
       
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

This last example is using PostData as a `NSObject` class as I showed you on the example above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please name structs with starting uppercase letter and variables with starting lowercase letter. The `init` method is not needed

```
struct PostData {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let imgURL: String
    let date: String
}
```

and

```
var dataPosts : [PostData] = []
```

Actually you have only to reload the table view after the loop **inside** the closure which receives the data asynchronously. The temporary array `data` is not needed.

```
func parsePosts() {
   let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Посты")
   
   databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
       for child in snapshot.children {
           let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
           let res = snap.value as! [String: Any]
           
           let title = res["Заголовок"] as! String
           let subtitle = res["Подзаголовок"] as! String
           let img = res["URL"] as! String
           let date = res["Дата"] as! String
           
           self.dataPosts.append(PostData(title: title, subtitle: subtitle, imgURL: img, date: date))
           print(self.dataPosts.count, " - inside cycle") // prints 1
       }
       
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

And delete

```
print(dataPosts.count) // prints 0
```

in `viewDidLoad`, it's useless.

Comment: No need for `DispatchQueue.main.async {` firebase callbacks run im main queue

Comment: Thank you, I'm not familiar with Firebase.

Comment: wow, it's a brilliant answer. I wonder why when I call a print(self.dataPosts) inside viewDidLoad() I get an empty array but when I call the same function inside a numberOfRowsInSection() - I get a full one. Is it connected with the asynchrony? I need to use this array in the other class (UITableViewCell) and console shows me that array is empty :(

Comment: As mentioned in the answer the database request works asynchronously, the closure is executed later in time.